# Should I be using Classes or Structs for elements stored in a Swift Array

Tags: swift, class, struct, dplyr

I would like to mutate a property in a Swift struct, stored within an array. 
I have done a reassignment dance, but that it doesn't feel right.

I'm encouraged to use Struct's where possible, however this relatively simple use case (below) is pushing me towards using Classes (Reference Types).

Should I be using `Classes` for `Game` and/or `Player`?

*Please find below a code sample .. with accompanying UnitTest*

**Test Summary**
• Create a Game
• Create two Players
• Add both Players to Game
• Send message to Game to decrementPlayer
• Game iterates over collection (`players`)
• Finds player and sends message decrementScore
• **Test Failed** - Players' scores **were not** as expected (60 & 70 respectively)

```
struct Game {
    fileprivate(set) var players = [Player]()
}

extension Game {
    mutating func addPlayer(_ player: Player) {
        players.append(player)
    }

    mutating func decrementPlayer(_ decrementPlayer: Player, byScore: Int) {
        for var player in players {
            if player == decrementPlayer {
                player.decrementScore(by: byScore)
            }
        }
    }
}


struct Player {
    var name: String
    var score: Int

    init(name: String, score: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.score = score
    }

    mutating func decrementScore(by byScore: Int) {
        self.score -= byScore
    }
}

extension Player: Equatable {
    public static func ==(lhs: Player, rhs: Player) -> Bool {
        return lhs.name == rhs.name
    }
}
```

---

```
class GameTests: XCTestCase {

var sut: Game!

func testDecrementingPlayerScores_isReflectedCorrectlyInGamePlayers() {
        sut = Game()
        let player1 = Player(name: "Ross", score: 100)
        let player2 = Player(name: "Mary", score: 100)

        sut.addPlayer(player1)
        sut.addPlayer(player2)
        XCTAssertEqual(2, sut.players.count)    // Passes

        sut.decrementPlayer(player1, byScore: 40)
        sut.decrementPlayer(player2, byScore: 30)
        XCTAssertEqual(60, sut.players[0].score) // Fails - score is 100 .. expecting 60
        XCTAssertEqual(70, sut.players[1].score) // Fails - score is 100 .. expecting 70
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add you test code too.

Comment: Will do .. thank you @picciano Separated the XCTestCase from existing code sample

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm encouraged to use Struct's where possible

Yes, that is problematic. You should be encouraged to use `struct`s where *appropriate*. Generally speaking, I find that `struct`s aren't always as appropriate as fashion dictates.

Your problem here is that the `for var player ...` statement actually makes a mutable copy of each player as it iterates and amends the copy. If you want to stick with `struct`s, you'll probably need to adopt a more functional approach.

```
mutating func decrementPlayer(_ decrementPlayer: Player, byScore: Int) {
    players = players.map {
        return $0 == decrementPlayer ? $0.scoreDecrementedBy(by: byScore) : $0
    }
}
```

Or a more traditional (and almost certainly more efficient) way would be to find the index of the player you want

```
mutating func decrementPlayer(_ decrementPlayer: Player, byScore: Int) {
    if let index = players.index(of: decrementPlayer)
    {
        players[index].decrementScore(by: byScore)
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd like to accept your answer .. thank you. Although, after giving it some thought and colleagues advice, I feel decrementScore method should return the new Player struct. and then do the assignment back into the array of players (using the index you describe above)  ... thank you for your time, and help.

Comment: @MDMonty Yeah I think the functional approach which looks more "clever" would be less efficient since it constructs a whole new array. I think my index method above would be the quickest but your method would probably get close to it after optimisation.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to mutate a property in a Swift struct, stored within an array. I have done a reassignment dance, but that it doesn't feel right.

Well, that's what you would have to do, since structs are not mutable in place. If you want to be able to mutate the object in place (within the array), you do need a class.

Answer (score 0):

The question that should be asked when deciding between value types (structs) and reference types (classes) is if makes sense to have duplicate instances.

For example take number 5, which is an Int. You can copy it as many times, it's cheap (as structs are), and doesn't pose problems if copied.

Now let's consider a `FileHandle`. Can it be a struct? Yes. Should it be a struct? No. Making it a struct means the handle will get copied whenever passed as argument or stored as property. Meaning everyone will have a different reference to that handle (intentionally ignoring copy-on-write). If one reference holder decides to close the handle, this indirectly invalidate all the other `FileHandle` references, which will likely trigger unexpected behaviour.

In your particular case, I'd say to make `Player`, a class. I assume the player will have some UI effects also, so it makes sense to be a reference type. However, if `Player` is used only for statistical purposes, then make it a struct.